# react-router-dom route not rendering in Safari via Firebase deploy when visiting direct link

Tags: firebase, safari, react-router-dom

When using react-native-dom as follows:

// index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root')) registerServiceWorker()
```

// App

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="appContainer">
        <Router>
          <div className="container">
            <Header/>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Website}/>
              <Route path='/docs' component={Doc}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Everything works as expected while on localhost, and even while in production on Chrome and FF, but Safari will not render anything if linking directly to a route like: `http://mysite/docs` or navigating to a route and then refreshing the browser.

I only recieve: `This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory.` .

The only other bit of info I can add is that this is a Firebase hosted site (I dont believe this to be the underlying issue, but it is worth noting)...

Has anyone experienced this or have any insight.  Nothing I have found is dealing with any particular browser issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so for anyone facing similar issues, Ill leave this here:
for any route you need to hit outside of navigation (direct link to route), set it as such in the `firebase.json`

```
"hosting": {
"public": "build",
    "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/docs",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        },
        {
          "source": "/other",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
        // or for a catch all
        // {
        //   "source": "**",
        //   "destination": "/index.html"
        // }
    ]
}
```